# How to make ActionLink's text respond to whether a user is authenticated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want the ActionLink's text property to say "Login" when the "User.Identity.Name" property is null.

When a user is logged in I want the ActionLink's text property to display the users name.

How do make my ActionLink's text property respond to both of these scenarios?

```
_LayoutPage's code:
  @Html.ActionLink((string)User.Identity.Name.ToString(), "Login", "Home", new { @Class = "navbar-login", id = "navbar-login" })

Controller's code:  
        public ActionResult _LayoutPage()
        {
            bool val1 = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            if (val1 == true)
            {
                // If current user is logged in, display the current users name.
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                // If user is null just say "Login"
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the user name in the login action link when user name is not null.  When user name is null, display "Login".

```
@{ 
    string loginDisplayText = User.Identity.Name ?? "Login";
}
@Html.ActionLink(loginDisplayText, "Login", "Home", new { @class = "navbar-login", id = "navbar-login" })
```

Comment: Good code, it helped a lot. I needed to add this along with your code to make it work.       if (User.Identity.Name == null || User.Identity.Name == "")
   {
      loginDisplayText = "Login";
   }

Comment: If you want to check if the string is null **or empty** you could also use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` .